# Compile matcaffe in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, matlab, caffe

I need to run an .m file that uses caffe. In Ubuntu 18.04 the installation of caffe is as simple as `sudo apt install caffe-cpu`.

How do I compile for Matlab afterwards?? If I run `caffe.reset_all();` in Matlab, I get an error “Undefined variable "caffe" or class "caffe.reset_all".”

`which caffe` in terminal gives me “/usr/bin/caffe”.

In Python I had no problem to import caffe.

I cannot imagine how everyone has figured it out and no one has problems except from this guy here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671854/how-to-install-matcaffe-and-pycaffe-on-ubuntu-17

I am using Matlab R2014b, because the official site of caffe mentions that it supports matcaffe interface.

I would really need your help. Thank you in advance!